# Filter a contenttype with list of content object's field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I creating an app where users can post with its related tags:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    activity = GenericRelation(Activity, related_query_name="posts")

class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.ImageField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    activity = GenericRelation(Activity, related_query_name="photos")

class Activity(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    verb = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=VERB_TYPE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

What I want to do is get/filter maximum of 5 latest/recent Activity objects, with the a list of users, and a list of tags from the list of Post objects tags field and return json using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to view in the client side.

Eg activities:

- UserA created a new Post obect with tags(#class, #school)
- UserB created a new Post object with tags(#professor, #teacher)
- UserC created a new Post object with tags(#school, #university)
- UserD created a new Post object with tags(#university, #school)

So say I want to filter Activity with `user_list=[UserA, UserC]` and `tag_list = [#class, #teacher]`

It should return:

- UserA created a new Post obect with tags(#class, #school)
- UserC created a new Post object with tags(#school, #university)
- UserB created a new Post object with tags(#professor, #teacher)

To filter the Activity with users, I can query this way:

```
Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=user_list)
```

But, how do I filter Activity with the content_object's (i.e.Post or Photo) field (i.e. Post.tags or Photo.tags)? Now I am doing this way:

```
Activity.objects.filter(posts__tags__in=tag_l)
Activity.objects.filter(photos__tags__in=tags)
```

So to sum up, If I have need activities with list of users and list of tags I have to do like this:

```
activites = Activity.objects.filter(
    Q(actor__in=user_list) |
    Qposts__tags__in=tag_list) |
    Q(photos__tags__in=tag_list)
)
```

But suppose there will be more than two ContentType model classes then I'd have to again add another `Q(moreModel__tags__in=tag_list)`. So, I hope there's a better way to optimize the process.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your best bet would be to use a filter from [Django filter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) (link to the rest framework docs), specifically a `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`. I'm going to assume you already have an `ActivityViewSet` to go along with the `Activity` model.

Firstly you'll want to create a `django_filters.FilterSet`, probably in a new file such as `filters.py`, and set up the `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`, like so:

```
import django_filters

from .models import Activity, Tag, User

class ActivityFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    tags = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        name='content_object__tags__name',
        to_field_name='name',
        lookup_type='in',
        queryset=Tag.objects.all()
    )
    users = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        name='content_object__user__pk',
        to_field_name='pk',
        lookup_type='in',
        queryset=User.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = (
            'tags',
            'users',
        )
```

Then you'll want to tell your viewset to use that filterset:

```
from .filters import ActivityFilterSet
# ...
class ActivityViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    # all your existing declarations, eg.,
    # serializer_class = ActivitySerializer
    # ...
    filter_class = ActivityFilterSet
    # ...
```

Once you've got that done, you'll be able to filter your results using GET parameters, eg.,

- `GET /activities?users=1` – everything created by User 1
- `GET /activities?users=1&users=2` – everything created by User 1 or User 2
- `GET /activities?users=1&tags=class` – everything created by User 1 with the tag #Class
- `GET /activities?users=1&users=2&tags=class&tags=school` – everything created by User 1 or User 2 with the tags #Class or #School
- and so on

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example from [django updown](https://github.com/weluse/django-updown), it have a similiar model: https://github.com/weluse/django-updown/blob/master/updown/models.py#L31

```
>>> from updown.models import Vote
>>> Vote.objects.first()
<Vote: john voted 1 on Conveniently develop impactful e-commerce>
>>> v = Vote.objects.first()
>>> v.content_object
<Thread: Conveniently develop impactful e-commerce>
>>> v.content_object.__class__
<class 'app_forum.models.Thread'>
>>> [ v.content_type for v in Vote.objects.all() if v.content_object.__class__.__name__ == 'Thread' ]
[<Thread: Conveniently develop impactful e-commerce>, <Thread: Quickly evisculate exceptional paradigms>]
>>> 
# You can also use with
>>> user_ids = [ u.content_type.id for u in Vote.objects.all() if u.content_object.__class__.__name__ == 'User' ]
>>> user_ids
[1, 52, 3, 4]
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.filter(pk__in=user_ids)
[<User: John>, <User: Alex>, <User: Roboto>, <User: Membra>]
>>>
>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> ContentType.objects.get_for_model(v.content_object)
<ContentType: Detail Thread>
>>>
```

You also can use `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model_instance)` such as this: https://github.com/weluse/django-updown/blob/master/updown/fields.py#L70

In your problem, maybe can use with this..

```
>>> photo_ids = [ ac.content_type.id for ac in Activity.objects.all() if ac.content_object.__class__.__name__ == 'Photo' ]
>>> Activity.objects.filter(content_type__id__in=photo_ids)
# or
>>> photo_ids = [ ac.content_type.id for ac in Activity.objects.all() if content_type.model_class().__name__ == 'Photo']
>>> Activity.objects.filter(content_type__id__in=photo_ids)
```

Hope it can help..

Comment: @Robin hello robin, now, in my currently project got similiar condition like your problem... I creating a forum that has a notification system... so, to handle it with creating a `receiver` and `sender` field.. hope my snippets useful for you: https://gist.github.com/agusmakmun/6607cbd13b7e6b06a0da97cd18b2ef22

Answer (score 0):

For this method set the related_query_name to the name of the model in lower case or verbose_name of the model.

You can first filter out the content type present in the `Activity` model.

```
content_types = ContentType.objects.filter(activity__id__isnull=False)
```

Now use these content types to build the lookup.

```
q = Q(actor__in=user_list)
for content_type in content_types:
    arg = content_type.name + '__tags__in'
    kwargs = {arg: tag_list}
    q = q | Q(**kwargs)
```

Now you can filter the activities using this lookup.

```
activities = Activity.objects.filter(q).distinct()
```

Comment: Hi, wont this hit the db two times? Also I want to get only the maximum of 5 latest activity objects, but in your first filter, it seems its querying the whole ContentType objects? Please correct me if I am wrong here?

Comment: Hi, yes you are right on both the points. I used the first filter to query all the content types. If you already know the related_query_name of different models on which you want to query, you could just pass the names in a list and construct the lookup by this method. This will skip the first query. For eg. `content_types = ['posts', 'photos']`. You can make a custom manager method of activity model and pass this list as argument which will decide the reverse relations to query.